# Regex that matches certain url parameters in arbitrary order

Tags: regex, nginx, url, url-parameters

Im trying to setup caching in NGINX and need to include just certain parameters (if given) to create a key and cache the site. But I don't get it to work if the parameters are in a different order or, as it is also possible, not given at all.

The URLs can be:

```
https://www.example.com/xyz/
https://www.example.com/xyz/?param1=123&param2=456&param3=789
https://www.example.com/xyz/?param2=456&param3=789&param1=123
https://www.example.com/xyz/?param3=789&param1=123&param2=456
https://www.example.com/xyz/?param1=123&param3=789&param2=456
https://www.example.com/xyz/?param1=123&param2=456
```

Only the path and `param1` (optional) and `param2` (optional) are relevant for caching. Other parameters should be ignored. So in the end I need three named capture groups that I can create a mapping for NGINX:

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
  "~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(?:\?.*)?(?P<p1>param1\=[^&]*)+(?:\&.*)?(?P<p2>param3\=[^&]*)+$"  $path$p1$p2;
}
fastcgi_cache_key "$scheme$request_method$host$request_uri_path";
```

But obviously my regex is not working https://regex101.com/r/Hf2jCj/1

```
~^(?P<path>[^?]*)(?:\?.*)?(?P<p1>param1\=[^&]*)+(?:\&.*)?(?P<p2>param3\=[^&]*)+$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a `map` you can add as many regular expressions as you need. The regular expressions are processed sequentially until a match is found. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) for details.

List the more specific patterns before the less specific patterns.

You might want to match URLs containing *param1+param3* and *param3+param1*, **before** patterns to match URLs with just one of the params, **before** matching the URLs with neither param.

For example:

```
map $request_uri $request_uri_path {
    ~^(?<path>[^?]*)\?([^&]*&)*(?<p1>param1\=[^&]*)([^&]*&)*(?<p2>param3\=[^&]*) $path$p1$p2;
    ~^(?<path>[^?]*)\?([^&]*&)*(?<p2>param3\=[^&]*)([^&]*&)*(?<p1>param1\=[^&]*) $path$p1$p2;
    ~^(?<path>[^?]*)\?([^&]*&)*(?<p1>param1\=[^&]*)                              $path$p1;
    ~^(?<path>[^?]*)\?([^&]*&)*(?<p2>param3\=[^&]*)                              $path$p2;
    ~^(?<path>[^?]*)                                                             $path;
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach for the problem of the less specific patterns. I also was able to change the Regex so the order of the parameters and additional parameters don't matter: `^(?<path>[^?]*)(?=.*(?<p1>param1=[^&]*))?(?=.*(?<p2>param3=[^&]*))?`